# Passing native string type from CLI to native and back again

Tags: c++, com, interop, c++-cli

I am trying to write a CLI wrapper around some low-level COM-related calls.  One of the operations that I need to do specifically is to get a specific value from a `PROPVARIANT`, i.e.:

```
pwszPropName = varPropNames.calpwstr.pElems[dwPropIndex];
```

where `pwszPropName` is documented to be an `LPWSTR` type and `dwPropIndex` is a `DWORD` value passed into the function by the user.

I have a native function defined as follows:

```
HRESULT CMetadataEditor::GetPropertyNameByID(DWORD ID, wchar_t *PropertyName)
```

I would like to return the value of `pwszPropName` via `*PropertyName`.

Is the `wchar_t*` type the best way to do this, and would I need to pin `*PropertyName` in my CLI to ensure it does not move in memory?  Do I need to define the length of `*PropertyName` before passing it to native code (buffer)?

If `wchar_t*` is the right variable type to pass into the native function, what is the proper conversion of `LPWSTR` to `whar_t*`, and how then would you convert that value to `System::String`?

I have tried a number of different techniques over the past few days and can't seem to get anything right.

---

------------UPDATE------------

Here is my full code.  First, the CLI:

```
String^ MetadataEditor::GetPropertyNameByID(unsigned int ID)
{
    LPWSTR mPropertyName = L"String from CLI";

    m_pCEditor->GetPropertyNameByID(ID, mPropertyName);

    //Convert return back to System::String
    String^ CLIString = gcnew String(mPropertyName);
    return CLIString;
}
```

And the native code:

```
HRESULT CMetadataEditor::GetPropertyNameByID(DWORD ID, LPWSTR PropertyName)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    LPWSTR myPropName;

    PROPVARIANT varNames;
    PropVariantInit(&varNames);

    hr = m_pMetadata->GetAllPropertyNames(&varNames);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        PropVariantClear(&varNames);
        return hr;
    }

    myPropName = varNames.calpwstr.pElems[ID];
    PropertyName = myPropName;
    PropVariantClear(&varNames);
    return hr;
}
```

It doesn't seem like the value (`myPropName`) is set properly and/or sustained back into the CLI function because the CLI returns the value I set on `mPropertyName` before calling the native function..  I'm not sure why or how to fix this.

---

UPDATE!!!!

I suspected my problem had something to do with variables going out of scope.  So I changed the C++ function definition as follows:

```
LPWSTR GetPropertyNameByID(DWORD ID, HRESULT ErrorCode);
```

After adjusting the CLI as well, I now get a value returned, but the first character is incorrect, and in fact can be different with every call.  I tried using `ZeroMemory()` in the native class before assigning the output of the `PROPVARIANT` to the variable (`ZeroMemory(&myPropName, sizeof(myPropName +1));` but still no luck.

Comment: Quacks like heap corruption.  Use a data breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks Hans I will, hopefully this afternoon.

Comment: One sentence refers to `LPWSTR`, another to `LPSTR`. Is `LPSTR` a typo?

Comment: It is in fact LPWSTR.  I've edited the post for clarity.  Thanks Tom.

Comment: I have modified the code to hopefully provide some clarity and direction as to what I am asking.

Comment: You need to pass the buffer to unmanaged function, like `GetPropertyNameByID(DWORD ID, LPWSTR PropertyName, size_t length)` and to copy `varNames.calpwstr.pElems[ID]` to this buffer using `wcscpy`, instead of pointer assignment (which doesn't have any effect for the caller).

Comment: Think, for example, how `GetComputerName` API is implemented, and do the same.

Comment: Thank you Alex!  I'll give that a try.  How do I know what size of buffer to pass?  I'll give `GetComputerName` a look.

Comment: Alex it worked great!  How do I mark your comment as the answer and close this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design unmanaged function by the following way:

```
HRESULT CMetadataEditor::GetPropertyNameByID(DWORD ID, LPWSTR PropertyName, size_t size)
{
    ....
    wcscpy(PropertyName, varNames.calpwstr.pElems[ID]);  // or wcsncpy
    ...
}
```

`PropertyName` is the buffer allocated by caller, `size` is its size. Inside the function `wcscpy` or `wcsncpy` the string `varNames.calpwstr.pElems[ID]` to `PropertyName`. Client code:

```
WCHAR mPropertyName[100];
m_pCEditor->GetPropertyNameByID(ID, mPropertyName, sizeof(mPropertyName)/sizeof(mPropertyName[0]));
```

Think, for example, how `GetComputerName` API is implemented, and do the same